# How to show the swagger-ui at my app root?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

In my spring boot application, I want to see the swagger-ui, whenever I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`.

I enabled swagger and redirected `/` to `swagger-ui.html` with this config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/swagger-ui.html");
    }
}
```

However, this makes my browser log this JavaScript-Exception:

```
springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at e (springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1)
    at springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
    at x (springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1)
    at Generator._invoke (springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1)
    at Generator.t.(:8080/myapp/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:8080/myapp/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1:50487)
    at e (springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1)
    at springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
    at window.onload (springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1)
e @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
x @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
t.(anonymous function) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
e @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
window.onload @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
load (async)
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
r @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
r @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
(anonymous) @ springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1
```

The first item of the stacktrace points to this line in `http://localhost:8080/myapp/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js?v=2.9.2`:

```
return/(.*)\/swagger-ui.html.*/.exec(window.location.href)[1]
```

How can I make my swagger api doc appear, when I open the root of my application?

The depenencies I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the requests with this change:

```
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui.html");
//                                           ^-- "redirect" instead of "forward"
```

If the user now navigates to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`, he will be redirected to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/swagger-ui.html`.

Answer (score 0):

redirecting to `swagger-ui` from `swagger` will solve this issue,

```
//Do redirection inside controller
@RequestMapping("/swagger")
public String greeting() {
    return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html";
}
```

you can try to add bean too, inside main method,

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
    return route(GET("/swagger"), req ->
        ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("swagger-ui.html")).build());
}
```

Comment: Will I have to use this URL: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/swagger`, or will it work for `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`, too?

Comment: @slartidan it wont work `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`, as you can see the GetMapping of `swagger`, it work when you put it in URL, you aare free to modify it